# How should I link a Django (2.1.4, Python 3.7) User and a Discord Account?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, discord.py

I am creating a Django website and trying to link a Discord account to the user, for listening to when the user is mentioned on the associated Discord server.

This is to be run with:

- Python 3.7
- Django 2.1.4
- Discord.py 1.0.0(a)

Being still quite new to Django, I do not really know where to start (I have looked on Google but can't find anything helpful).

Here is the code for *views.py*:

```
import discord

token = open('token.txt', 'r').read()
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'{message.channel}: {message.author.name} ({message.author}): \n 
{message.content}')

client.run(token)
```

I have not been able to run it yet, not being able to figure out the Discord account linking.

Comment: Are you just looking to get a msg when you get mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I'm using/going to use the Django messages package combined with Minimalize toasts in order to display it to the user.

Comment: There is a package on PyPI: https://github.com/mrogaski/django-discord-bind It looks a bit outdated (Django 1.x), but looking at their source code could provide you some insight.

Comment: Is there an easy way to update their source code? I could add it to my _models.py_ which is currently empty.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to accomplish using discord.py with django?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @uno - life got a bit in the way of this project, so I don't think I did in the end.